# TabControl with different Views and ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel, tabcontrol

Right now, my application has 1 `TabControl` in the `MainWindow`. I have about 10 TabControls and each TabControl has about 25-50 Controls so the XML code is pretty big and is very slow in editing even in Blend. Is there a good solution to this problem?

I thought about making each tab a `Page`. Then, have a TabControl in the MainWindow and place in each Content of the Tabs a Page. Unfortunately, this isn't possible as far as I know because Visual Studio throws errors at me like these:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '10'.

Comment: How about making each tab a user control?

Comment: Yea, figured that out a little ago and started trying some stuff. Works out great :) Tnx for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Using UserControls instead of Pages.